# Accessing network files from asp.net. What permissions do I need?

Tags: iis, permissions

I have a web app that loads files from another server on the network.  It's causing an error that I believe is related to it not having proper permissions to access the files.

I know very little about configuring iis, or how to configure permissions on other machines for iis to be able to access so I'm hoping someone could lead me in the right direction here to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running IIS 7 then most likely your application is running as Network Service. If you are running a domain then this account will access network shares as the computer object from AD. So you need to explicitly give the web server computer access to the share.

If you are not running a domain you have to change the user - network service without a domain cant access windows shares. Even if they are available to guest users.